# How to remove an element which is not on the top of the stack?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

This is my code:

```
void removeOddValues(Stack *s)
{
    Stack *odd = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    odd->ll.head = NULL;
    odd->ll.size = 0;

    while(s->ll.head->item % 2 == 0){
        push(odd, s->ll.head->item);
    }
    pop(s);

    while(!isEmptyStack(odd)){
        push(s, odd->ll.head->item);
        pop(odd);
    }
    free(odd);
}
```

How can I remove the elements that are in the middle of the stack?

Answer (score 3):

Stack can be accessed only from the end, so the algorithm for removing items from the middle of a stack requires a second stack for temporary storage of data:

1. Pop an item from Stack One
2. If you would like to keep the item, push it on Stack Two
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until Stack One is empty
4. Pop an item from Stack Two and push it on Stack One
5. Repeat step 4 until Stack Two is empty

Answer (score 2):

Stack by its definition(i.e. LIFO) does not support intuitively removing elements in the middle. It is not recommended to use stack if you need to remove elements that are not at the top. However, **if you have to** do it, then you may simply use a second stack to store the elements that you do not wish to remove, as you search whichever one you intend to remove.

Let's call your original stack S<sub>1</sub>. Basically you will allocate a second stack S<sub>2</sub>. Then, the following is a rough pseudocode of how you will handle deletion.

```
while you still have elements to remove:
    item = pop from S_1
    if NOT item is to be removed:
        S_2.push(item)

//once removal is done
while S_2 is NOT empty:
    S_1.push(S_2.pop)
```

This approach maintains the original relative order of the elements in S<sub>1</sub>.

**Note that, however, this method would be sub-optimal**, as this operation is not optimal in terms of space and time, albeit by a constant factor. You better use some other data structure than a stack to be able to implement it optimally.

Answer (score 1):

All provided answers are fine. But you are making a new stack. You can perform delete operation on the same stack.
Here is the code :

```
struct Node* deleteValue(struct Node *node, int value){
    struct Node* temp = NULL;
    struct Node* curr = node;
    if(node == NULL)
      return node;
    else if(node->data == value){
        temp =  node;
        node = node->next;
        free(temp);
        return node;
    }
    while(curr->next != NULL){
       if(curr->next->data == value){
           temp =  curr->next;
           curr->next = curr->next->next;
           free(temp);
           break;
       }
       curr = curr->next;
   }
   return node;
}
```